# server.close() doesn't work in a Vow teardown

Tags: node.js, vows

I'm trying to write some Vows-based tests for my run-of-the-mill Express app.

Here's the test source:

```
var vows = require('vows');
var assert = require('assert');
var startApp = require('./lib/start-app.js');

var suite = vows.describe('tournaments');

suite.addBatch({
    "When we setup the app": {
        topic: function() {
            return startApp();
        },
        teardown: function(topic) {
            if (topic && topic.close) {
                topic.close();
            }
        },
        "it works": function(topic) {
            assert.isObject(topic);
        }
    }
});

suite.run();
```

And here's `start-app.js`:

```
var app = require('../../app.js');

function start() {
    var server = app.listen(56971, 'localhost');
    return server;
}

module.exports = start;
```

`app.js` exports a regular Express.js app, created with `express()`.

The problem is that whenever I run the test, `topic.close()` doesn't work in the teardown function, and the test hangs forever after succeeding. I've tried searching the web and adding lots and lots of `console.log`s, all to no avail.

I'm on the Windows x64 build of Node.js 4.2.0, and I'm using `assert@1.3.0` and `vows@0.8.1`.

Any idea how I can make my test stop hanging?

Comment: Same problem here, test builds on Travis run forever. Did you find a solution?

Comment: @FernandoPiancastelli I never found a proper solution, but as a dirty hack, calling `.unref()` on the `topic` object "fixed" this. I suspect there's a bug somewhere, possibly in Node core...

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I did to solve the issue in a project I was contributing: a final batch just to close the server.

```
suite.addBatch({
  'terminate server': {
    topic: function() {
      server.close(this.callback); // this is a regular node require(`http`) server, reused in several batches
    },
    'should be listening': function() {
      /* This test is necessary to ensure the topic execution.
       * A topic without tests will be not executed */
      assert.isTrue(true);
    }
  }
}).export(module);
```

Before adding this test, suite would never end executing. You can check the results at https://travis-ci.org/fmalk/node-static/builds/90381188

Comment: nice, but it doesn't solve my problem because the server is used as the topic. so there's no reference to it outside of a batch.

Comment: That seems related to an open bug [link](https://github.com/vowsjs/vows/issues/229), where teardown won't be called if your `topic()` doesn't call `this.callback`. Coincidentally, my code calls it.
If I recall node VM correctly, if you create another topic, in another batch, that returns `starApp()` again and immediately closes it, it might work since it'll treat your `require('./lib/start-app.js')` as a singleton, and hence close it's only listener.